# Change class toggle to multiple span element with Jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I need to change the class of a span child that uses a toggle when I click on one of the browser rows.
But it only works when there is a single row, when there are several rows it does not find the span and it does not work.

I also tried to use the href to select the correct span, but I don't know how to use it in the JQuery code

````
<div>
<a id="menu-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#01" class='btn btn-default' title='Ver pagos'>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
</a>
</div>
<div>
<a id="menu-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#02" class='btn btn-default' title='Ver pagos'>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
</a>
</div>

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#menu-toggle').on('click', function() {
    var $el = $(this),
    textNode = this.lastChild;   
    var $href = $(this).attr('href');
    var $href = $href.substring(1);
    $el.find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
  });
});```
````

Comment: `id;s` must be unique for each element. you have duplicate `id's` - use class instead to handle click on both `menu-toggles`

Comment: $('#menu-toggle').each(function(index) {
    // access dom using $(this)});

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var el = 2
for(var i=0; i<el.length; i++) {  
  document.getElementsByClassName("glyphicon").find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon- 
  chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I simplified the code so I commented the span and then call with the function onclick CambiaClass, using a class data1, data 2 ... dataN (to identify the item) and now is working fine.

**Thanks for your help Rahul!!!**

```
<a id="menu-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php echo $id_item; ?>" 
class='btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down <?php echo 'dato'.$id_item; ?>' 
title='Ver pagos' onclick="CambiaClass('<?php echo 'dato'.$id_item; ?>')">
    <!-- span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span --> 
</a>

//Jquery
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CambiaClass(idclass) {
      $("[class*='"+ idclass+"']").toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up');
    }
</script>
```